Why is there no error if a class defines a member with the same name and type as the class it inherits? Which of the two members is used?
I am currently learning programming in university and I was messing around and wrote this code and I got curious:
class Student{
public:
    string name;
    string address;
};

class Instructor: public Student {
public:
    string name;
    string address;
};

int main() {
    Instructor Z;
    Z.name = "Zombie";
    cout << Z.name;
    return 0;
}

Shouldn't C++ return an error since both classes one of which inherits contain the same data type (string) with the same name (name)? And also when we delegate Z.name = "Zombie"; does the object take from the Student class or the Instructor class?

There is nothing to stop two different classes having members with the same name, even if one inherits fom the other. The issue is which member is used in a given context, and that's a question about name lookup. In your case the Instructor member is used.

Incidentally, inheritance usually implies an "is a" relationship. An Instructor is a Student is probably not correct, so Instructor should not be derived from Student. But if you change the name of the class Student to Person it all fits together.

To answer the title, there's nothing that forbids this in the language, thus, no error. Compilers may have warnings for this though.

You'll have to qualify which name you actually want to use. The unqualified name is the one from the actual type. Observe:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


class Student{
public:
    std::string name{"empty"};
    std::string address{"empty"};
};
class Instructor:public Student {
public:
    std::string name{"empty"};
    std::string address{"empty"};
};

int main() {

    Instructor Z;

    std::cout << Z.name << "\n";
    std::cout << Z.Student::name << "\n\n";

    Z.name = "Zombie";

    std::cout << Z.name << "\n";
    std::cout << Z.Student::name << "\n\n";

    Student& S=Z;
    std::cout << S.name << "\n";

    S.name="Student";
    std::cout << S.name << "\n\n";

    std::cout << Z.name << "\n";
    std::cout << Z.Student::name << "\n\n";
}

stieber@gatekeeper:~ $ g++ Test.cpp && ./a.out
empty
empty

Zombie
empty

empty
Student

Zombie
Student

So, there are simply two distinct name variables. Same for address, of course.
